# Get text area value as php variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have a text area field and I want to get value as variable so that I can use these variable to fetch data from mysql.

```
<?
$sms = $_POST['message'];
$whatIWant = substr($sms, strpos($sms, "#") + 1); 
echo $whatIWant;
?>
```

[this is a image of textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q6aa.png)

I tried these code but it's not output as I want. 
How can I retrieve variables from this input value? Thanks

Comment: what results are you wanting to get as opposed to what you're getting now?

Comment: I am now getting whole value of textarea and it's working fine. Now I want to get dynamic value from text area. when I add the value to text area `hello #name#` I want to get this name as variable and later with this variable i want to fatch result from mysql. (something like dynamic personalised bulk email or sms sending app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
$str  = 'Hello #Fahim#. Im from #Mazegeek,Inc#. My phone no is #011111#';

preg_match_all('/(?<=#).*?(?=#)/', $str, $m);

print_r($m);
```

let me know if it works.